# Why are these two urls redirecting to the same page?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I am using

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=a&i=$1
RewriteRule ^b/(.*)/?$ index.php?page=b&i=$1
```

to redirect urls of the form `mysite/something` to `index.php?page=a&i=something` and `mysite/b/something` to `index.php?page=b&i=something`. However, both urls are redirecting `index.php?page=a&i=something`. Why is this happening?

Comment: your first `^(.*)/?$` will match `mysite/b/something`,and `^b/(.*)/?$` don't match anyone

Comment: Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)$ index.php?page=a&i=$1
^[^\/]+\/b\/([^\/]+)$  index.php?page=b&i=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

`.*` in first rule will match everything.

To prevent this behavior you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^b/(.+?)/?$ index.php?page=b&i=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?page=a&i=$1 [L,QSA]
```